# Coffeescript - Finding substring with "in"

Tags: coffeescript

In Coffeescript the following gives `true`

```
"s" in "asd" # true
```

but this gives false

```
"as" in "asd" # false
```

- Why is this?
- It happens with strings with more than 1 character?
- Is `in` not suited for this task?

Comment: Don't forget to accept the answer, it's a nice one!

Comment: Thanks! I forgot!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`x in y` syntax from coffeescript expects `y` to be an array, or array like object. Given a string, it will convert it into an array of characters (not directly, but it will iterate over the string's indexes as if it were an array).

So your use of `in`:

```
"as" in "asd"
# => false
```

is equivalent to

```
"as" in ["a","s","d"]
# => false
```

This way it is much easier to see why it returns false.

The [little book of coffeescript](https://arcturo.github.io/library/coffeescript/04_idioms.html) has this to say on `in`:

> ## Includes
>
> Checking to see if a value is inside an array is typically done with indexOf(), which rather mind-bogglingly still requires a shim, as Internet Explorer hasn't implemented it.
>
> ```
> var included = (array.indexOf("test") != -1)
> ```
>
> CoffeeScript has a neat alternative to this which Pythonists may recognize, namely in.
>
> ```
> included = "test" in array
> ```
>
> Behind the scenes, CoffeeScript is using Array.prototype.indexOf(), and shimming if necessary, to detect if the value is inside the array. Unfortunately this means the same in syntax won't work for strings. We need to revert back to using indexOf() and testing if the result is negative:
>
> ```
> included = "a long test string".indexOf("test") isnt -1
> ```
>
> Or even better, hijack the bitwise operator so we don't have to do a -1 comparison.
>
> ```
>  string   = "a long test string"
>  included = !!~ string.indexOf "test"
> ```

Personally, I would say that the bitwise hack isn't very legible, and should be avoided.

I would write your check with either `indexOf`:

```
"asd".indexOf("as") != -1
# => true
```

or with a regex match:

```
/as/.test "asd"
# => true
```

or if you are using ES6, use [`String#includes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes)